# .Net Core Application Parts, change view import/search location

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-routing

I've been experimenting with ASP.NET Core application parts, but have ran into two problems:

- Firstly, I need a way to specify an extra directory in the view engine's search path, some of the time.
- Secondly, is there any way to change the import location of views when pulled in through application parts?

The reason I am asking is due to some of my application parts having identically named controllers and views (i.e., Home/Index) which causes AmbiguousMatchExceptions. I have already relocated the controllers using a namespace routing scheme detailed here: [.net core replacement for MvcCodeRouting. Namespace based routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60332757).

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Do you want this way of specifying extra directories in the view engine's search path?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36747293/how-to-specify-the-view-location-in-asp-net-core-mvc-when-using-custom-locations

Comment: @Chaodeng Thanks for your help, I'd seen that post some time ago but wanted a more "manipulatable" approach if possible. I did find a way in the end and have documented it and marked it as the answer. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An implementation of the `IViewLocationExpander` interface did the job in this case.

By creating an implementation of the `IViewLocationExpander`, you can specify alternative locations, in which, views may be located. The "default" locations are passed into the `ExpandViewLocations` method (which returns an `IEnumerable<string>`), only the locations returned are searched, meaning that you get the choice to either include the defaults or leave them out, forcing only your newly specified locations to be searched.